# Historical fantasy manhwa where the female lead dies after execution for a crime she didn't commit to protect her friend

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, manga, webcomics

The female lead is transported into a noble's body and becomes friends with a boy (bastard prince). She dies for him after he executed his father for the crown and then wakes up again as a young girl because prince turns back time with his powers.

Random things I remember:
The dad dies in a carriage accident... Two twin cousins who are friends w/ them to, one becomes a priest and the other a soldier...
They all made a time capsule, and she dug it up early...
She sacrificed herself cause she thought it would end the story or something... "It's over now" or something haunted male lead

I swear I'm not crazy but I can't find it anywhere!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead?

Answer (score 4):

Is this ***[I Raised My Childhood Friend as a Tyrant](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/pqhhm1e/i-turned-my-childhood-friend-into-a-tyrant)***...?

> A young Korean woman is reincarnated inside a novel as Viche Amelian, who according to the story, is to be executed in place of the young prince Jade for assassinating the emperor. After facing her death, she expects to get her old life back, but instead wakes up as a 10-year-old Viche! Could it be that her death failed to turn Jade into a tyrant, as the story foretold? Viche must now figure out where she went wrong, and make sure that this time, Jade becomes the world’s most wicked tyrant!

A Korean office worker is transmigrated into a novel as Viche Amelrian, the childhood friend of Prince Jaidel. As an adult, she confessed to and was executed for the murder of Jaidel's father, the Emperor, who was killed by Jaidel himself. She then wakes up in the past, when she and Jaidel were ten years old.

Jaidel's cousins -- twins Benjamin and Duffrey Louischelsa -- play a prominent role early in the story, and there's a scene where the four childen bury a time capsule which they plan to dig up five years later. Jaidel also chooses to study magic.

[image] [image]